Insert after closing ERB tag with spree/deface
there is a project called TheForeman (v3.3.0) for which I want to override some ERB templates with spree/deface (v1.5.3), for example _managed.html.erb, and add something at the end of it.
# in app/overrides/nic/manageds/_managed/add_my_partial.html.erb.deface
<!-- insert_after "erb[loud]:contains('nic/provider_specific_form')" -->
<%= render 'my/partial', :f => f %>

Works great! Now, there are 5 more templates of the same kind, where the same approach works. But then I have to supply the identical .deface for each template. It would be more sensible and maintainable if I were to put my partial at the end of the other partial, which is rendered in each template (my current deface select target), right? Sadly, I failed to achieve that with deface, which brought me here.
What I've tried so far...

deface cannot go directly to the end of a file
deface insert_after cannot use closing_selector and it looks like it doesn't recognize which ERB elements start and end Ruby blocks

selecting erb[silent]:contains('if') inserts as second line in the file
selecting erb[silent]:contains('end') inserts three times, once after each <% end %>


Using :root or :last as CSS selectors yield very strange results I cannot explain. Both select more than the root and final elements, which makes no sense.
The CSS selector last-of-type seems to be completely ignored and therefor erb[silent]:last-of-type selects every silent ERB element
nth-child seems to be processed, but...

erb[silent]:contains('end'):nth-child(3) hits nothing
erb[silent]:nth-child(5) hits the second <% end %>
erb[silent]:nth-child(6) hits nothing


erb[silent]:nth-last-child(1) after each <% end %>
:root>erb[silent]:contains('end') inserts after the second <% end %>
Since I failed to find any example for deface's cut action, I wouldn't know how to paste whatever was cut back for other ludicrous tests like...

Cut everything
insert my partial
insert before my partial what was cut



Maybe, if there was a way to let deface show me the concrete pseudo HTML markup of an ERB file, I could experiment with CSS selectors against that. At this point I cannot extrapolate that in my imagination far enough.
I welcome any hints!
Thank you for your time,
Xavier.


if there was a way to let deface show me the concrete pseudo HTML markup of an ERB file (...)

That, in fact, wasn't so difficult:
require 'deface'
raw_erb = File.open(path_to_erb_template).read
puts Deface::Parser.erb_markup!(raw_erb)

Which produces...


<erb silent> if provider_partial_exist?(@host.compute_resource, &amp;#39;network&amp;#39;) </erb>
  <erb silent> hidden = f.object.virtual? ? &amp;quot;hidden&amp;quot; : &amp;quot;&amp;quot; </erb>
  <fieldset  data-erb-class="compute_attributes &lt;%= hidden %&gt;">
    <h3 class="col-md-offset-1">
      <erb loud> @host.compute_resource.provider_friendly_name </erb>
      <erb silent> if f.object.compute_attributes[&amp;quot;from_profile&amp;quot;] </erb>
        <span class="profile">( <erb loud> _(&amp;quot;from profile %s&amp;quot;) % f.object.compute_attributes[&amp;quot;from_profile&amp;quot;] </erb> )</span>
      <erb silent> end </erb>
    </h3>

    <erb silent> new_vm = @vm ? @vm.persisted? : new_vm?(@host) </erb>

    <erb loud> f.fields_for &amp;#39;compute_attributes&amp;#39;, OpenStruct.new(f.object.compute_attributes) do |f| </erb>
      <erb loud> render provider_partial(@host.compute_resource, &amp;#39;network&amp;#39;), :f =&amp;gt; f, :disabled =&amp;gt; f.object.persisted?, :compute_resource =&amp;gt; @host.compute_resource, :new_host =&amp;gt; new_vm, :new_vm =&amp;gt; new_vm </erb>
    <erb silent> end </erb>
  </fieldset>
<erb silent> end </erb>



On www.videlibri.de I could interactively test CSS selectors against that. The solution then was found quickly and is rather simple: :root:last-child


[foreman@host ~]# foreman-rake deface:get_result[nic/_provider_specific_form] 
                                                                          ---------------- Before ----------------
<% if provider_partial_exist?(@host.compute_resource, 'network') %>
  <% hidden = f.object.virtual? ? "hidden" : "" %>
  <fieldset class="compute_attributes <%= hidden %>">
    <h3 class="col-md-offset-1">
      <%= @host.compute_resource.provider_friendly_name %>
      <% if f.object.compute_attributes["from_profile"] %>
        <span class="profile">( <%= _("from profile %s") % f.object.compute_attributes["from_profile"] %> )</span>
      <% end %>
    </h3>

    <% new_vm = @vm ? @vm.persisted? : new_vm?(@host) %>

    <%= f.fields_for 'compute_attributes', OpenStruct.new(f.object.compute_attributes) do |f| %>
      <%= render provider_partial(@host.compute_resource, 'network'), :f => f, :disabled => f.object.persisted?, :compute_resource => @host.compute_resource, :new_host => new_vm, :new_vm => new_vm %>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>

---------------- Overrides (1)--------
- 'add_my_partial' will be applied.

---------------- After ----------------
<% if provider_partial_exist?(@host.compute_resource, 'network') %>
  <% hidden = f.object.virtual? ? "hidden" : "" %>
  <fieldset class="compute_attributes <%= hidden %>">
    <h3 class="col-md-offset-1">
      <%= @host.compute_resource.provider_friendly_name %>
      <% if f.object.compute_attributes["from_profile"] %>
        <span class="profile">( <%= _("from profile %s") % f.object.compute_attributes["from_profile"] %> )</span>
      <% end %>
    </h3>

    <% new_vm = @vm ? @vm.persisted? : new_vm?(@host) %>

    <%= f.fields_for 'compute_attributes', OpenStruct.new(f.object.compute_attributes) do |f| %>
      <%= render provider_partial(@host.compute_resource, 'network'), :f => f, :disabled => f.object.persisted?, :compute_resource => @host.compute_resource, :new_host => new_vm, :new_vm => new_vm %>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
<%= render 'foreman_cnames/hosts/host_aliases', :f => f %>


---------------- Diff -----------------
 <% if provider_partial_exist?(@host.compute_resource, 'network') %>
   <% hidden = f.object.virtual? ? "hidden" : "" %>
   <fieldset class="compute_attributes <%= hidden %>">
     <h3 class="col-md-offset-1">
       <%= @host.compute_resource.provider_friendly_name %>
       <% if f.object.compute_attributes["from_profile"] %>
         <span class="profile">( <%= _("from profile %s") % f.object.compute_attributes["from_profile"] %> )</span>
       <% end %>
     </h3>

     <% new_vm = @vm ? @vm.persisted? : new_vm?(@host) %>

     <%= f.fields_for 'compute_attributes', OpenStruct.new(f.object.compute_attributes) do |f| %>
       <%= render provider_partial(@host.compute_resource, 'network'), :f => f, :disabled => f.object.persisted?, :compute_resource => @host.compute_resource, :new_host => new_vm, :new_vm => new_vm %>
     <% end %>
   </fieldset>
 <% end %>
+<%= render 'my/partial', :f => f %>
+



